# InDesign: changing default font from English to Hebrew

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting

I have an English document. I need to paste some Hebrew text instead of the English one. How do I change the default font so that all the text I paste will be in this new font?

All I could find is how to change the default font for new files.

Comment: Do you have the multi-language version of InDesign?

Answer (score 1):

The default font is controlled by the [Basic Paragraph] style sheet. You can edit this in a new document you've just opened, in an existing document, or without any documents open.

The [Basic Paragraph] style is in the Paragraph Styles tab.

[image]

To edit the style, double click the title, or right click > Edit "[Basic Paragraph]...

[image]

There you can set the default font settings for any new copy you place in your document.

[image]

If you edit this with a document open, the changes will be for that document only. If you edit this without any documents open, the changes will be saved for any new documents you create.